# Si paso el valor por referencia, ¿me modifica el valor fuera de la función?

Tags: php

Me explico: una vez realizado el PHP necesito ponerlo bonito con HTML. Uno de los requisitos es que se muestren los créditos que tengo. Como estos varian segun el nº que salga, he pensado en pasarlo como referencia porque he leído que modifican el valor de la variable fuera de la función,(esta muy mal explicado en los apuntes). Esta sería la idea:

```
    function partida(&$creditos) {
        if ($creditos > 9) {
            $fichas = 0;
            $creditos -= 10;
            $num1 = math . random_int(0, 9);
            $num2 = math . random_int(0, 9);
            $num3 = math . random_int(0, 9);
            $resultado = array($num1, $num2, $num3);
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($resultado); $i++) {
                switch ($resultado[$i]) {
                    case 2:
                        $fichas += 25;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        $fichas += 100;
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        $fichas += 5;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                $creditos += $fichas;
                $comentario = "has conseguidos $fichas de premio";
            }
        } else {
            $comentario = "no hay suficientes creditos";
        }
        echo $comentario;
        return $creditos;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: En este caso no es necesario que pases el parámetro por referencia, porque no hay nada que lo justifique. Con que retornes el valor modificado bastaría. Las ventajas son dos: a) Mayor claridad en el código; b) Mayor rendimiento. PHP no es como C o Java, donde pasar por referencia podría optimizar el código y aportar otras ventajas, en PHP es lo contrario. [Esta es una de las mejores respuestas sobre el tema](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/188784). Al final hay varios enlaces que te ayudarán un formarte un criterio sólido sobre el uso de referencias en PHP.

Answer (score 0):

¿Por qué quieres modificar el parámetro créditos si ya los estás devolviendo al final (return $creditos)? En general lo preferible es no modificar los parámetros si es posible.

Intuitivamente, los parámetros no se suelen modificar, por lo que si alguien usa tu función de esta manera:

```
$creditos = 9;
$nuevosCreditos = $this->partida($creditos); // Ahora nuevosCreditos = 7 y $creditos = 7
echo "El usuario tenía $creditos y ahora tiene $nuevosCreditos"
```

Puede que se sorprenda de que el resultado sea:

```
El usuario tenía 7 y ahora tiene 7
```

Esto no quiere decir que no debas usar el paso por referencia nunca, hay casos que no vas a tener más remedio que usarlo, pero deberías en general tener una justificación para hacerlo y documentarlo en el PHPDOC si es posible.

EDIT: Imagínate que no lo pasas por referencia y lo pasas por valor. Puedes seguir encadenando partidas y seguir manteniendo todos los valores sin perder ni machacar informacion:

```
$inicial = 9;
$partida1 = $this->partida($inicial);
$partida2 = $this->partida($partida1);
$partida3 = $this->partida($partida2);
```

Si te da igual machacar el valor puedes llamar a la función así, pero esta libertad la dejas al usuario de la función, no se la impones tú como implementador de la función:

```
$inicial = $this->partida($inicial);
```

Comment: Vengo de java y no se de esto apenas, puesto que la siguiente vez que juegue la partida parto de los nuevos creditos entiendo que el parametro debe de modificarse para que la proxima partida no parta de 100 si no de los que tenga ahora

Comment: He editado la respuesta con lo que mencionas en el comentario

Comment: eso de $inicial  = $this -> patida donde lo meto?

Comment: @unknow `$inicial = $this->partida` no aplica para este caso. `$this` se usa dentro de las clases, por ejemplo para obtener el valor del miembro `partida` de una clase, harías `$inicial = $this->partida`, pero aquí no estamos dentro de un método o función de una clase.